# IE9 rounded corners and transparent background issues

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have searched a lot, but I can't really find an answer to this.

I have rounder borders all over, everywhere it's fine, except on the elements which are using img as background (image get nice rounded corners, but behind is some sort of black background).

PICTURE for easier understanding of the issue:

[image]

I'm really stuck on this. Any suggestions is this IE issue or am I missing something?

CSS of gray header is something like this:

```
#header {
    background-image: url("images/bg-header.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 46px;
    line-height: 46px;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #332829;
    width: 575px;
}
```

FIDDLE:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/2BnDR/2/
```

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle demo that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Will try too to do it...

Comment: @bažmegakapa http://jsfiddle.net/2BnDR/2/ --- it's not IE9, because i can't replicate it, i guess...

Comment: Checked your demo and don't see the problem in IE9. Maybe try to add that red circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured that IE9 does wierd black background arround element and bugs like you can see on the print screen above. When you have box-shadow or text-shadow + filter on same element.

I've deleted all filters out of my CSS and it works as charm.

Eg.

```
.header {
    filter: dropshadow(color=#3e3132, offx=0, offy=-1); /* delete this one and it works */
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #3e3132;
}
```

Comment: +1 I was also facing this problem and found the cause in your answer

Answer (score 1):

try this maybe:

```
#DivThatImageIsIn img{
  border-radius: same as div;
}
```

Comment: I've posted CSS of header... Hope it helps.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2BnDR/2/ --- it's not IE9, because i can't replicate it, i guess...